# case when result inaccurate

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
SELECT
 DATE_TRUNC('day', payment.paid_at) AS "DAILY",
 COUNT(CASE WHEN product.type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "A count",
 SUM(CASE WHEN product.type = 'A' AND payment.price_currency_code='USD' THEN payment.price_amount*1080 ELSE payment.price_amount END) AS "A revenue",
 COUNT(CASE WHEN product.type = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "B count",
 SUM(CASE WHEN product.type = 'B' AND payment.price_currency_code='USD' THEN payment.price_amount*1080 ELSE payment.price_amount END) AS "B revenue"
```

Hi,

I have a question when using "CASE WHEN"
I've written the query as above but the outcome is inaccurate. In fact, the sum of revenue per each category calculates almost same amount when in reality it should be different (the count is correct though).

Would appreciate if you can point out what I'm missing or have done wrong!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in your ELSE statements, because it is including everything else, when in fact you probably intended a different condition:

```
SELECT
 DATE_TRUNC('day', payment.paid_at) AS "DAILY",
 COUNT(CASE WHEN product.type = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS "A count",
 SUM(CASE WHEN product.type = 'A' AND payment.price_currency_code='USD' THEN payment.price_amount*1080 WHEN product.type = 'A' THEN payment.price_amount END) AS "A revenue",
 COUNT(CASE WHEN product.type = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS "B count",
 SUM(CASE WHEN product.type = 'B' AND payment.price_currency_code='USD' THEN payment.price_amount*1080 WHEN product.type = 'B' THEN payment.price_amount END) AS "B revenue"
```

Also, in a case statement ELSE NULL is not necessary since NULL is the default result for non-matches.

Comment: Oh right! Thank you for your help, this solved the problem nicely :) Thank you!